# For loop open netcdf files in different directories

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray

I am new to python and looking to open specific netcdf files in different directories so I can average and plot them (surface temperature data)

The directories are in yyyy/mm/dd/filename. (Two nc files for each day, day and night).
I.e I want to open all the files in 2002/07/daytime, and then so on for every month of 2002-2018.
How do I do this please? I'm looking into for loops and xarray but I can't work it out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to use glob to create a list of all files, then use open_mfdataset to combine them automatically.

```
from glob import glob
import xarray as xr

list_files = glob('./*/*/*/*.nc')
#Create a list of all nc files with a path matching this format :
#whatever(year)/whatever(month)/wathever(day)/whatever(file name).nc

DS = xr.open_mfdataset(list_files)
```